# How to focus JDialog programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, focus, jdialog

I have read some of those similar threads here but they did not help me.
I have my JDialog that is undecorated and initially is unfocusable:

```
super(connectionsTree.getMainFrame(), "", false);
        super.setUndecorated(true);
        super.setFocusableWindowState(false);
        super.setFocusable(false);
super.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        super.pack();
```

Now whenever this dialog is visible and user tpes Space button I must make that JDialog focused so that it receives key events.
I do it like so :

```
if (keyCode == 32) {
            tooltip().setFocusable(true);
            tooltip().setFocusableWindowState(true);
            tooltip().requestFocusInWindow();
        }
```

This code makes my JDialog focusable but JDialog is not focused and key events are not grasped by it.
`tooltip()` method only returns instance of my JDialog.

How to make my JDialog receive focus programmatically?

Thank you!

Comment: What is `tooltip()`? What does it do?

Comment: this method only returns instance of my JDialog which should receive focus by requestFocusInWindow() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) of `requestFocusInWindow()` focus to `Component` will be granted only if top level parent component is focus owner. So this will not work if your main window has no focus on it. You should use `Component#requestFocus()` instead.
From `Component#requestFocus()` description

> Requests that this Component get the input focus, **and that this Component's top-level ancestor** become the focused Window.

Comment: I accepted it. requestFocusInWindow() means that component within window receives focus whereas requestFocus() method means that window itself receives focus.